# Leaflet - Can I use a different background tile provider depending on zoom level?

Tags: leaflet, tiles

This may look strange, but I cannot made up my mind between providers of satellite tiles for Leaflet. ESRI sattelite looks beautiful, but cannot reach the zoom level I need. HERE is not nice on low zoom levels, but goes as deep as I want.

Can I use ESRI for low zooms and HERE for high ones?

How do I do this?

Do you think it is wise?

Comment: It is absolutely fine to switch layers programmatically depending on zoom. Afaik, you have to explicitly add/remove layers from the baselayers array. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/leaflet-js/1gQyZhOADCg

Answer (score 3):

It's fine to use different tile sources for different zoom levels, just set the min and max zoom on each layer, and don't have the zoom ranges overlap.

```
    var map = L.map('map').setView([45, -110], 10);
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        minZoom: 0,
        maxZoom: 10
    }).addTo(map);
    L.tileLayer('http://tile.stamen.com/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        minZoom: 11,
        maxZoom: 16
    }).addTo(map);
```